# Powershell - array - Concatenate two arrays separated with comma

Tags: arrays, powershell

What I have?

$array1 = "string01", "string02", "string03"

$array2 = "another01", "antoher02", "anoter03"

What I wish?

output-file:

- Example01:

string01,another01

string02,another02

string03,another03

How can I cocatenate two arrays in one and do that line by line? It's because I need to combine value 01 from $array01 with value01 from $array02, separating them with comma.

I have tried to use foreach, but this one combine every value from $array01 with every value from $array02, for example:

- Example02:

string01,another01

string01,another02

string01,another03

string02,another01

string02,another02

string02,another03

string03,another01

string03,another02

string03,another03

But I need the output likes the Example01.

I am using powershell! Thanks

I have tried to use foreach, but this one combine every value from $array01 with every value from $array02, but no success doing that!

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `For` loop to do this simply. Something like:

```
For($i=0; $i -lt $array1.count; $i++){
    $array1[$i],$array2[$i] -join ','
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0) does exactly what you're looking for:

```
$array1 = 'string01', 'string02', 'string03'
$array2 = 'another01', 'antoher02', 'anoter03'

[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Zip(
    [string[]] $array1,
    [string[]] $array2,
    [Func[string, string, string]] {param($x, $y) "$x,$y" })

# Outputs:
# string01,another01
# string02,antoher02
# string03,anoter03
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this with a ForEach loop. There are probably a million ways to skin this cat.

```
ForEach($x in $array1){
    $index = $array1.IndexOf($x)
    $combined += @($array1[$index] + "," + $array2[$index])
}
```

In the above block the current item in the loop is going to be $x, we get the index of $x from $array1 because that's the array we are looping. We just use that index on the other array, and we glue it all together by concatenating with "+" symbols.

Output of $combined:

```
string01,another01
string02,antoher02
string03,anoter03
```